# Add layer keywords to WMTS GetCapabilities response using GeoServer?

Tags: geoserver, metadata, wmts, getcapabilities

In the past I have been entering keywords in "Edit Layer" section of GeoServer. These keywords have shown up on a per layer basis in the "KeywordList" section of a WMS GetCapabilities response, which has allowed me to create a layer tree for my map application. I have recently moved over to using WMTS GetCapabilities requests, however these responses do not show the "KeywordList" section. Is there a way to get this metadata to show up in WMTS GetCapabilities responses?

I have seen there is a "INSPIRE extension" for GeoServer which says it can expand WMTS metadata requests, however after installing it successfully, I have been unable to get the "KeywordList" section to show up. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: The INSPIRE extension adds service level metadata, so I don't think that it will help with layer metadata.

Comment: It is schema valid to have keywords in the Layer description (after the Abstract), in a WMTS  Capabilities response document, but I agree I cannot see any way (either through the GUI or by editing the XML configuration files) of adding them

Comment: You might want to consider raising an enhancement request on the GeoServer issues log

Comment: Good idea, I will do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I have not been able to find a way to add the "KeywordList" to WMTS GetCapabilities responses, however I have found a simple workaround. I do both a WMS and WMTS GetCapabilities request for each layer and then use the "KeywordList" from the WMS request to inform the WMTS layers as seen below:

```
for (let layer of capabilities.Contents.Layer) {

    // find the matching WMS layer
    const wmsLayer = wmsCapabilities.find(wmsLayer => wmsLayer.Name === layer.Identifier);
    const wmsKeywords = wmsLayer.KeywordList;
    const wmtsOptions = ol.source.WMTS.optionsFromCapabilities(
    capabilities, { layer: layer.Identifier, matrixSet: 'EPSG:27700' }
                        );

    layer.KeywordList = wmsKeywords;

    const olLayer = this.createWMTSLayer(geoserverBaseUrl, layer, wmtsOptions);
}
```